# How can I prove this using Fitch notation?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I have a little problem.  I need to prove the following statement using Fitch notation. Can anyone help me out? :)

**|= (t → s) ∧ ¬((s → q) → (t → q))**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you mean $\vdash$ instead of $\models$? In any case this isn't true.

Comment: Nop, that's correct. Btw, can u simply tell me why?

Comment: It is incorrect as $t \rightarrow s$ is not a validity.

Comment: Thank you. What a stupid guy that i am.. Thank you a lot James

Answer (score 1):

Using a truth table what is desired to be shown is a contradiction:

[image]

That means its negation is a tautology. That tautology can be derived using Fitch-style natural deduction as follows:

[image]

---

Stanford Truth Table Tool http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/tools/truth-table-tool/

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/